# Programmatic way to select what to screen share?

Tags: google-chrome, screensharing

[image]

There is a popup window like above that shows up.

I'm guessing that's a security thing where the remote person can't decide what to share... even if it's done by websocket/JS that runs on the person sharing.

Comment: What's the use case here? Most software allows for screen selection, and all of that software is coded programmatically. Which begs the question - why are you trying to screen share through Chrome in the first place?

Comment: This is screen sharing without downloading a desktop client. Just wanted to know if it's possible to programmatically select what to share with code vs. the popup/user has to click on it. I mentioned I could see if it's a security concern.